# Calculate $\iint_D x\ln(xy) dx\,dy \text{ where } x = 1, x = e, y = \frac{2}{x}, y = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Ok this is a sample exercise from the book that I don't know how to solve.

> Calculate $\iint_D x\ln(xy) dx\,dy \text{ where } 1 \le x \le e , \frac{2}{x} \le y \le \frac{1}{x}$

The answer is $(\ln4 -1)(e - 1)$ but I can't figure out why.

I thought to change order or integration but I'm not successing to do it.

Can you please help me solve it? thanks.

Comment: Writing $D$ seems necesary here...

Comment: With $x=1$... are you trying to describe $D$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $1 \le x \le e , \frac{2}{x} \le y \le \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: The, edit your post.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Edited

Comment: Reversed, I suppose. Idea: $1\le xy\le 2$ suggests a change of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_1^\text{e}\left( \int_\frac{2}{x}^\frac{1}{x}x \ln(xy)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
To make the computations more clear lets figure out the first integrand first.
$$
\int_\frac{2}{x}^\frac{1}{x}x \ln(xy)\;\mathrm{d}y
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c c}
u = \ln(xy)& v' = 1\\
u' = \frac{1}{xy}\cdot x & v= y
\end{array}
\right]
=
x\left(\left[
y\cdot\ln(xy)
\right]_{2/x}^{1/x}
-\int_\frac{2}{x}^\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y}\cdot y\; \mathrm{d}y
\right)
=
x\left(
\left(\frac{\ln 1}{x}\right)-\left(\frac{\ln 2}{x}\right)-\left[y\right]_{2/x}^{1/x}
\right)
=
x\left(-\frac{1+\ln 2}{x}\right)
=
-1-\ln 2
$$
And then just put it into the first integrand and integrate once more.
$$
\int_1^\text{e} -1 -\ln 2\; \mathrm{d}x
=
-(1+\ln 2)\left[x\right]_1^\text{e}
=
-(1+\ln 2)(e-1)
$$
Well, it seems I've made some numeric mistakes, but hopefully the integrating process is clear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better if you integrate on $y$ first and on $x$ second. Now, you have the integral
$$\int_1^e \left(\int_{1/x}^{2/x} x \ln(xy) dy\right)dx.$$

Carry the $x$ out into the second integral and calculate the integral $\int_{1/x}^{2/x}\ln(xy) dy$. You get some function of $x$ which you can then integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Make a change of variables
$$\varphi\colon\;\;\pmatrix{x\\y}\mapsto \pmatrix{u\\v}$$
by
$$\begin{cases}
u=x,\\
v= xy.
\end{cases}$$
Then $$\dfrac{\partial(u,\,v)}{\partial(x,\,y)}=\pmatrix{ \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}& \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\\\dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} & \dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}}=\pmatrix{y&x\\1&0},$$
so $$\det{\dfrac{\partial(u,\,v)}{\partial(x,\,y)}}=x\ne{0}$$
in $D,$ therefore the Jacobian determinant 
$$\det{\dfrac{\partial(x,\,y)}{\partial(u,\,v)}}=\dfrac{1}{u}.$$
Additionally, $D'=\varphi(D)=\{(u,\,v)\colon\;\; 1\leqslant{u} \leqslant{e},\;\;{1\leqslant{v}\leqslant{2}}\}.$
Then
$$\iint\limits_{D} {x\ln(xy)} dx\,dy=\iint\limits_{D'} {u\ln{(v)}} \dfrac{1}{u}\ du\,dv= \int\limits_{1}^{e}{\left(\int\limits_{1}^{2}{\ln{(v)}\ dv}\right)\ du}$$